# Bible for \expandafter and \relax

Tags: expansion

I'm looking for a good document about the use of `\expandafter` and `\relax`. This is to try to learn LaTeX programmation more seriously by really understand the expansion mechanism of LaTeX.

Comment: Read the TeXbook.

Comment: You want to learn TeX primitives? Then _TeX by Topic_ is the way to go: I'm sure we have several older questions saying much the same :)

Comment: Related: A Tutorial on `\expandafter` [TUGboat 9:1 (1988)](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb09-1/tb20bechtolsheim.pdf)

Comment: `\relax` is a primitive that does nothing. It doesn't expand, it doesn't do anything when executed. It would be a small document:-) (`\expandafter` is more interesting)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're forgetting the delights of a `<filler>` and also the usage of `\relax` in e-TeX.

Comment: Let's go for TeX by topics... Thanks a lot !